# Cannot format a string to DateTime in "MM/dd/yyyy"

Tags: c#, datetime, date-format

My data XML stores the date with "MM/dd/yyyy" format. 
However, when displaying the date on my page, it is shown as '12/12/2006 12:00:00 AM' for example.

I'm trying to convert it to the format I need:

```
OrderDate = DateTime.ParseExact(rows[4].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None)
```

But that does not help and the date is displayed with the wrong format.

How can I retain the format from how data is stored in XML?

Comment: so you want to remove the hours?

Comment: You do realise that `12/12/2006 12:00:00 AM` is identical to `12/12/2006`?

Comment: `OrderDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, I guess. I just do not understand why the time is not displayed the way it is coming from XML

Comment: Why would a `DateTime` variable display the same way as a `string` variable?

Comment: First explain *how* you are dispaying the date, then we can suggest ways to help.

Comment: Date is coming from XML file as 'MM\dd\yyyy'. I need to show date exactly as it is coming from XML. I have an object with OrderDate storedas DateTime and when getting the data from XML, I need to convert it to DateTime with 'MM\dd\yyyy' format. When using `ToString()`, I have a conversion error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Read these,
1)http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/
2)https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx
hope you'll find everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just need to use a `ToString()` when you want to display it.

```
OrderDate.ToString("d");
```

This will display it in the short date pattern for the selected culture.

Have a look at the MSDN [DateTime.ToString documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) and [information on standard Date and Time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: OrderDate in my example is stored as DateTime

Comment: In any use case I can think of, it will be converted to a String before being displayed. That's not to say there aren't any out there.

Comment: A comment on the downvote would be appreciated, I honestly thought I had given a helpful answer, would be good to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format in the `ToString` method. If you want it in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, then you just pass that to the method. Otherwise, the default is to include the time part of the `DateTime` object, which defaults to `12:00:00 AM`.

If you're getting exceptions trying to parse the date from the XML, then it's likely that the format being stored doesn't match the format you're passing to `ParseExact`. One way to get around this would be to try to parse it using the `TryParseExact` and `TryParse` methods (which return false if they fail), using a few different methods if the first one doesn't succeed: one with a 4 digit year, one with a two digit year, and one not specifying any expected format (note that using a single digit month and day works for double-digit inputs in these fields):

```
var xmlDate = "03/20/17";
DateTime orderDate;

// The first 'TryParse...' that succeeds will store the parsed date in 'orderDate'
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(xmlDate, "M/d/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    DateTimeStyles.None, out orderDate))
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(xmlDate, "M/d/yy", new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        DateTimeStyles.None, out orderDate))
    {
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(xmlDate, out orderDate))
        {
            // Couldn't parse, so use a default date, or log an error..?
            orderDate = DateTime.Today;
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: Unable to convert to date: {xmlDate}");
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Order date: {orderDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")}");
```